# Closed Questions

Tags: feature-request, delete

Is there no policy to close and, once closed, to subsequently delete, remove and make no longer visible questions that have no answers and are clearly not on topic.

A good eg. would be [I was wanting to know if anyone thinks that ceasar could be satan?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/63349/i-was-wanting-to-know-if-anyone-thinks-that-ceasar-could-be-satan)

Is there a reason to keep these in the stack, wasting space and attracting more clicks which prove worthless time wasters? I'm not a 'clean freak', but these just seem to be clutter.

Answer (score 1):

We don't normally bother manually deleting them because [the system will delete them automatically after some time](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/roomba). So that question will be deleted in 9 days time, most likely.

Comment: ok, thx for the heads up!